# How to pass a variable from class in python/gtk?

Tags: python, gtk

I am developing a program in python using gtk to create a GUI for a program, this program I am trying to pass a variable that I create in a class A to a class B, but I am not able to do that, I'm trying to do something like this:

```
class ClassA(gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ClassA, self).__init__()
        self.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)
        self.button = gtk.Button("Button")
        self.button.connect("clicked", self.on_clicked)

    def on_clicked(self, *args):
        variable = "value"
        ClassB(variable)

class ClassB(variable, gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ClassB, self, variable).__init__()
        self.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)
        self.button = gtk.Button("Button")
        self.button.connect("clicked", self.on_clicked)
    def on_clicked(variable, *args):
        print variable

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = ClasseA()
    gtk.main()
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Among other things, you're confusing argument-passing with inheritance. You're going to have to familiarize yourself with basic OOP before you can take on GTK; set GTK aside for now and take a look at the Python tutoral -- especially the section on [classes](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class ClassB(gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self, variable):
        #Your code
        self.variable = variable
```